# Show a table field's column headers in template?

Tags: templating, matrix, table-field

The question says it all.

I have:

- A Matrix field, with
- A subfield with the type table
- Two columns within that table of which I want to show the column headers in my template

Is that possible and if yes, how?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You don't get table headings with the entry model data (use the `dump()` function while in dev mode to see yourself). But there's the method `getFieldByHandle()` that returns a [field model](http://buildwithcraft.com/classreference/models/FieldModel) containing info to any field settings.

### This is how you access the headings of a table field

#### Craft 2

```
{% set field = craft.fields.getFieldByHandle('myTableField') %}

{% for column in field.settings.columns %}
    <li>{{ column.heading }}</li>
{% endfor %}
```

#### Craft 3

```
{% set field = craft.app.fields.getFieldByHandle('myTableField') %}

{% for column in field.settings.columns %}
    <li>{{ column.heading }}</li>
{% endfor %}
```

**Table field in Matrix block:**

As fields within matrix blocks don't necessarily have unique field handles, you can't use the `getFieldByHandle()` method to get the field model. Use the unique field ID with the method `getFieldById()` instead. To look that ID up, open up the source code of the field in the matrix field's field settings. There's a div with the class `matrixconfigitem` and a data attribute `data-id`, which is the ID you are looking for.

*(PS: use the code in your matrix loop for the block type containing your table "sub" field to output in the right place, but it actually works everywhere!)*

Comment: what would then be my handle? Tried it with the handle value of the subfield of the blocktype, get an error because the field cannot be found {{ dump(field) }} returns NULL.

Comment: Yep sorry. It's a little different with fields in matrix blocks, @paul.

Comment: Thought so, already tried your approach ;)

Comment: Does the smily mean the approach works for you? If yes, what about accepting / up voting the answer?

Comment: No, the smily means that I had already tried the approach you mentioned and it didn't work for me. I would have gladly upvoted your answer if it would have been the solution I was after, of course.

Comment: Ahh, you mean you tried such an approach before asking the question. Why didn't you mention it?

Comment: @Paul why is `getFieldById()` not working for you? What's the error you get?

Comment: Sorry carlcs, only now I see your edit. Mea culpa. Will try and upvote if it works.